# Syncing Blender footage with motion tracking camera without post-edit?

Tags: 3d-view

This might not be the right place to ask this question, but since the Blender community has really talented people, it is worth a shot, because I really do not know who else to ask.

I wanna combine the motion-tracking camera with rendered blender video (that goes in the loop) as a background, but without post-edit. I wanna sync my movement from the motion tracking camera with rendered footage from the Blender. So when I am walking around the greenscreen (and I am always in the middle of the camera scene, because of the motion-tracking stand), I need to sync Blender footage to follows me.

Before we continue, It does not have to be 360 footage. I wanna use one wall and use a motion-tracking camera in panoramic style. From left to right with around a 90-degree angle.

Here is a couple of things that I was thinking about how this can be achieved.

I am assuming that the best bet would be to separate blender video from a motion-tracking camera and then use some kind of layering with mirrors in some software? I have no problems with the motion-tracking camera following me where I am always in the middle of the scene, so my only problem is the background part. How to sync it?

Is there any program or video player that can do that? Is it possible to use my chroma keyed body as a "cursor" that can move the blender video behind?
Are there any sensors that can tell some program where I am so the footage syncs?

I know it is complicated, sorry if this made you confused. If you have any questions, please fill free to ask.

Comment: Could you please add some references my brain cannot comprehend what you are trying to do.

Comment: Blender is not the tool to do real time keying or motion tracking, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: https://youtu.be/Q7YUl7eF9u8 Add some tracking markers to the footage that camera sees (on the green screen maybe) so blender can convert their movement to virtual camera movement. Also ì didn't watch this, but it seems relevant https://youtu.be/TK6FeXOCwQI